# Multi-layered bidirectional_dynamic_rnn: incompatible with MultiRNNCell?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I want to create a multi-layered bidirectional LSTM in Tensorflow. Currently my single-layered model looks like:

```
cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_size)
cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_size)

(self.out_fw, self.out_bw), _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw, cell_bw, input, ...)
```

In order to turn this into a multi-layered I suspect I can *not* simply wrap a few `LSTMCell`s with `MultiRNNCell`s like so:

```
multi_cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell_fw] * num_layers, ...)
```

and feed them into the `bidirectional_dynamic_rnn` since both forward and backward LSTMs in each layer need the output of both the forward and backward directions of the preceding layer. Currently my solution is to create my `bidirectional_dynamic_rnn`s in a loop, feeding in the concatenated output of LSTMs of the preceding layers.

However, it's not very clean and frankly I'm not sure if it's correct, though it does work on a toy dataset. Is there a better way that's comparably elegant to using something like `MultiRNNCell`?

I'm using Tensorflow API r1.0.

Comment: I'm in the same position as you were. Any conclusion from your previous experience?

Comment: I just stuck with the solution I had, using a loop to create the layers. It works, but isn't as elegant as one would hope.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

`multi_cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell_fw for _ in range(num_layers)], ...)`

That should work.